# What does a Mysql-ssl connection require in NodeJs for the handshake

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl

I have seen two main ways to secure the mysql connection in NodeJs.
First :

```
const db_config = {
   user: process.env.DB_USER,
   database: process.env.DB_NAME,
   password: process.env.DB_PASS,
   host: process.env.DB_HOST,
   ssl : {
       ca : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'),
       rejectUnauthorized: false
   }
}
```

But I have also seen :

```
const db_config = {
   user: process.env.DB_USER,
   database: process.env.DB_NAME,
   password: process.env.DB_PASS,
   host: process.env.DB_HOST,
   ssl : {
       ca : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca-server.pem'),
       key : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-key.pem'),
       cert : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-cert.pem'),
       rejectUnauthorized: false
   }
}
```

The question is are the `cert` and `key` important for the ssl connection ? How do their absence affect the handshake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, the client (node.js) is using a certificate authority bundle to ensure that the certificate that the *server* presents is somehow chained to one in that bundle.

This ensures that the client can trust *who the server is*.

In the second example, **in addition to the above verification**, the client is also providing its own certificate to the server so that the server can verify the client is authorized. This is a form of mutual authentication, in which the client ensures it can trust the server is who it says it is and the server can trust the client says who it says it is.

Scenario 1: provides a TLS connection to the server, verifies the server is who it says it is.

Scenario 2: provides a TLS connection to the server, verifies the server is who it says it is, server is able to verify the client is one of the expected, authorized clients.

Comment: So. If I understand. There is two ways to use SSL and a server can chose not to accept the first scénario ? for example if I only give the ```ca``` , the server could reject the connection if it does not accept the scénario 1.

Comment: I would phrase it as: "An encrypted connection can be opted-into easily. On top of an encrypted connection, a client can verify the server's identity if it wants to. The server can verify the client's identity if the client presents a certificate and it wants to do so."

The client can reject the connection if the server's certificate doesn't match (or isn't chained to the bundle). The server can reject the connection if the client presents a certificate and the client's certificate does not match what the server expects.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't affect the handshake

By the time you can use

```
   key : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-key.pem'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client-cert.pem')
```

To `login` into mysql, you have already established a secure connection.

If they are **missing** it will user **username and passowrd**

With

```
ca : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca-server.pem')
```

you say that you trust the host, but the certificate will still test if it belongs to the host. Like isaid, you have then establushed a connection, to use username/password or the ssl credentials(given by the ca)